# Round button CSS loading animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a website to use my Kinect on. 
My hand is the mouse, so I've created an indicator when a button is activated.

The first thing I thought about was a round button, with a 2px white border, using a hover effect. When hovering over the button for 2 seconds, the border or a line inside the border should change to a different color, such as blue, to indicate progress/time passing.

After the 2 seconds of hovering over the button, it should get a click event, to navigate to another page, for example.

When I unhover the button, the loading process should slowly go backwards.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9pzVQ/1/

```
<a href="#" class="menu-arrow" onclick="showMenu('mnu_searches', event, 0, this)">Hover me!</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $("a.menu-arrow").hover(function() {
        $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
          $(this).click();
        }, this), 2000));
      }, function() {
        clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
      });
    });

    function showMenu() {
        alert("showMenu function fired");
    }
</script>
```

A diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL70X.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you right. I used pure javascript and a little of css for hoovering button effects.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var timer;

button.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
 timer = setTimeout(function(){
   alert('load new website now!');
  },2000);
});

button.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
 clearTimeout(timer);
  //location.replace("http://imgur.com/RdYotvd");
})
```

```css
.menu-arrow{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  border: solid 4px white;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:white;
  padding:5px;
  transition: border-color 2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-arrow:hover{
  border-color:#33aaff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button" class="menu-arrow" onclick="showMenu('mnu_searches', event, 0, this)">Hover me!</a>
```

Comment: The functionally of the fade is great, i thought more something like this:

https://youtu.be/_MTLU5Qddqs?t=41s

I hope this example is more clearly